# What is the name of the 4d shape that is equivalent to a cylinder except in 4d where 3 dimensions are equidistant from the center line instead of 2..

Tags: geometry, terminology

Sorry if my question is poorly explained. Basically I want the name of the shape that always looks like a sphere in 3 dimensions when fed into 3d space standing up in the 4th dimension; just like how a cylinder always looks like a circle in 2d flatland if you feed it into the 2d plane standing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ordinary cylinder is the Cartesian product of a $2$-ball and $1$-ball; you are looking for the Cartesian product of a $3$-ball and $1$-ball, which is a [**spherinder**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherinder).
[image]